# access smarty associative array

Tags: php, smarty

array1:

```
         [test1] => Array
                    (
                        [inside1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 2
                                [2] => 3
                            )
                        [inside2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 2
                                [2] => 3
                            )
                      )
```

I want to directly access value of **inside2** in smarty, without using loop.

Comment: that's very nice of you

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
hello {$varname.test1.inside2[0]}
```